# Dynamically setting the text of different DOM elements with a loop

Tags: jquery

I need to create a dynamically populated form containing a mix of

```
<select class="formElement">...</select>
<label class="formElement"/>
```

tags. After retrieving the data from the database I now want to loop through the results and populate the form, like this:

```
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    $('.formElement').val(data[i]);
}
```

My problem is that the `.val()` method only applies select (but not label) tags, and `.text()` only applies to label (but not select) tags. What are my options?

*Edited for clarity

Comment: `val()` does apply to `input` tags too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use element with class selector (if you have same class for different elements). To add options to select dynamically and text to label try this:

```
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){ 
     $('select.formElement')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",data[i])
         .text(data[i]));
    $('label.formElement').text(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: i think he just need to get the value of input fields.

Comment: This worked:                               $('input.formElement).text(data[i]); $('select.formElement).val(data[i]); $('label.formElement).text(data[i]);

Answer (score 0):

you can use val() for input tags,